# How to add a new region in between two existing regions?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, composite

I am trying to add a new region in between 2 already existing regions in a Composite UI application using Prism and C# 4.0.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Your question is unclear, trying to add new region in between already existing region, OK but what's the problem stopping you from that ?

Comment: How do i add it ? i m unable to find any code snippets anywhere on google ?

Comment: Can you tell us more what exactly you are looking for? If its about creating a new region you can create a new control and give it a region name and start adding views to it. If its about adding a new view you can use the view injection or view discovery.

Comment: Need to add a windows control hosted in winforms host to a new region which lies in between two already existing regions..

Comment: Apologies for the vague question , i just started off PRISM today ..